# Event Forwarding Broken - Wecutil.exe command gets stuck

Tags: windows-event-log, winrm

I am writing a software program that relies very heavily on event forwarding. It uses a collector-initiated subscription. After the subscription is created it works fine, as expected. Sometime later, could be a week or a month, the subscription will fail. Events will no longer get forwarded. When I run the command "wecutil gr" it gets stuck. If I try to view the subscription through the event viewer, the event viewer will freeze up and I will have to kill the event viewer task to close it. Once I get to this point the event forwarding will not work again. The only way to fix it is to reinstall the Windows Management Framework. I started observing this issue about 3 years ago running Windows 7 Professional.

Below is the configuration:

```
<Subscription xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/03/windows/events/subscription">
  <SubscriptionId>Subscription</SubscriptionId>
  <SubscriptionType>CollectorInitiated</SubscriptionType>
  <Description>Subscription</Description>
  <Enabled>false</Enabled>
  <Uri>http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/windows/EventLog</Uri>
  <ConfigurationMode>Custom</ConfigurationMode>
  <Delivery Mode="Pull">
    <Batching> 
      <MaxLatencyTime>5000</MaxLatencyTime>
    </Batching>
    <PullSettings> 
      <Heartbeat Interval="60000" />
    </PullSettings>
  </Delivery>
  <Query>
                  <![CDATA[
            <QueryList>
                <Query Id="0" Path="SourceLog">
                    <Select Path="SourceLog">*</Select>
                </Query>
            </QueryList>
        ]]></Query>
  <ReadExistingEvents>false</ReadExistingEvents>
  <TransportName>http</TransportName>
  <TransportPort>5985</TransportPort>
  <ContentFormat>RenderedText</ContentFormat>
  <Locale Language="en-US" />
  <LogFile>ForwardedEvents</LogFile>
  <CredentialsType>Default</CredentialsType>
  <EventSources>
  </EventSources>
</Subscription>
```

Does

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How many clients are connected to this collector ? Can you still see the subscription with `wecutil es` and `wecutil gs <subscription name>` ? Can you tell us which Windows' edition you use on the collector side ?

Comment: Only 1 client was connected when it failed. Yes, both of these commands run fine. Currently the collector is using Windows 10 Enterprise 1803.